Jupyter notebook shell, show output, even without newline
%%bash
echo -n 1
sleep 5
echo 3

This prints 1 only after the 5 seconds.
Therefore characters without a newline, such as progress bars do not show.
Is there a way to display the characters printed even if a newline was not printed yet?

You may be more interested in the bash kernel and this thread entitled 'Bash cells show no intermediate output'.

By the way, this post 'how to get jupyter %%bash to display output in real time' seems related ;however, the proposed solutions no longer work. For example, %%system runs yet now waits until the end to display the output ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].

Did you try the following?:
!echo -n 1
!sleep 5
!echo 3


I see in JupyterLab (versions 3.4.8 and 4.1.5) right now it shows the 1 and then five seconds shows the 3. They end up on the same line with 13 showing in the output.
